# Android License Checker --working example--

Tags: android

I have lost a day of coding trying to read every article on web in regards to settingup the License Checker for app.
Looking for the best working example for the LVL as it seems it must have changed due to tutorials around web have code that Eclipse does not recognize? Or the library is not loading right? Even that has changed from 'Google Marketing License' to 'Google Play License' in SDK under 'extras'.. no mention of this in all on-line tutorials.. thinking.. changes were recent with Jelly Bean ? Documentation in developer.android,com is also outdated it seems in same respect.. as usual.. urgh..

Any update recent insight into this would be MUCH appreciated?
Seems all examples/tutorials were around the 2010 era, and now zilch to match these differences mentioned... is it not used anymore? too hackable i understand but still useful i think..

Please advise?

Thank you in advance.
Droidster

Comment: It would be much easier to help you if you provided your code that isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

The Google Play Licensing Library comes with some sample code, and also the source file for the license validation. I found it necessary to link the source for these license validation classes into my Eclipse project.

The page [Setting Up for Licensing](http://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/setting-up.html) suggests including the source into your src directory, but just adding it as another source directory seems a better solution.